# How to use xslt:evaluate() to evaluate an expression

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a sample XML as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <additionalprice>12.90</additionalprice>
        <currencyvalue>60</currencyvalue>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <additionalprice>10.90</additionalprice>
        <currencyvalue>68</currencyvalue>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <additionalprice>30.90</additionalprice>
        <currencyvalue>80</currencyvalue>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <additionalprice>15.90</additionalprice>
        <currencyvalue>90</currencyvalue>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <additionalprice>11.90</additionalprice>
        <currencyvalue>20</currencyvalue>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I have my XSLT as shown below:

I want to introduce another column called "Total Price" which is equal to 
price + (additionalPrice*currencyvalue) . This is just my random expression . I want to use xslt:evaluate( ) for this. Although there could be better methods, I want to practice evaluate to understand the same. Could anyone please let me know how can I do that...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Another column in XSLT 3 with an evaluated expression would be `<td xsl:expand-text="yes">{price + (additionalPrice*currencyvalue) }</td>`. If you want to learn XSLT 3 and `xsl:evaluate` then I suggest you start with the examples in the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#evaluate-examples and try to adapt them. But your code nowhere requires dynamic XPath evaluation.

Comment: based on the obtained tota price, is it possible to sort the table using evaluate() ?

Comment: Sort is simply done with `perform-sort` e.g. `<xsl:perform-sort><xsl:sort select="td[3]/xs:decimal(.)"/><xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd"><tr><td>...</td><td>...</td><td xsl:expand-text="yes">{price + (additionalPrice*currencyvalue) }</td></tr></xsl:for-each></xsl:perform-sort>` or directly by using `xsl:sort` with the `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: If you need to see an `xsl:evaluate` example with context then perhaps http://xslt-3-by-example.blogspot.de/2017/06/using-xslevaluate-and-path-function-to.html helps.

Comment: Ok.. thanks @Martin. I actually somehow wanted to apply evaluate() here.

Comment: A good blog @Martin